# Can a hexblade's pact weapon count towards a set bonus?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, equipment

A hexblade's pact weapon gains "your implement's enhancement bonus, critical hit effect, properties and powers" when conjured from an implement held in the off hand. If "belonging to an item set" count as "properties", and the pact weapon is conjured from an implement that belongs to a set, does the pact weapon then count as another item that belongs in that set?

For example, say my hexblade can treat light blades as implements and is holding a Rhythm Blade Shortsword in his offhand- the rhythm blade shorsword counting as part of the Blade Dancer Regalia set. Since the pact weapon is derived from the Rhythm Blade Shortsword, would it count as another part of the Blade Dancer Regalia set and, together, the two swords would qualify for the 2 item bonus?

Comment: Perhaps a relevant question: would holding two Rhythm Blade Shortswords count as having two items? Because the the pact weapon might also “copy” that deeply, i.e. also count as another Rhythm Blade Shortsword.

Comment: Well, the hexblade's pact weapon is explicitly a certain kind of weapon- a star pact hexblade's weapon, for instance is a Longsword (albeit with 1d10 damage), a gloom pact Hexblade's weapon is a scourge, etc. As such, if the enchantment copied it wouldn't be a "Rhythm Blade Shortsword" but a "Rhythm Blade Longsword"- two different weapons.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is such a corner case that it is not covered by the rules.

**I would say it does not count into the set.**

In my opinion either the pact weapon copies completely, in which case the two essentially identical items are only counted once, or it copies superficially, and it does not belong to the set.

However, ruling otherwise would not upset game balance, so you should jusk ask your DM.